# Use of XPath.compile() is vulnerable to XPath injection

Tags: java, xml, sonarqube

Sonar raises critical issue, during static code analysis when XPath.compile is used

Have used common-langs.StringUtils.escapeXml to validate the input string

But still sonar shows the same

```
XPathExpression nodePathExpression = xpath.compile(nodeName);
```

Is there any way to fix sonar issue, other than whitlisting the inputstring ?

Comment: mark the issue as false positive :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sonarqube issue itself points out some interesting references, [this one](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/643.html) seems to be the most helpful one.

> Use parameterized XPath queries (e.g. using XQuery). This will help ensure separation between data plane and control plane.

or

> Properly validate user input. Reject data where appropriate, filter where appropriate and escape where appropriate. Make sure input that will be used in XPath queries is safe in that context.

I guess the second option wont resolve the sonarqube issue, because sonarqube does not detect that you validate the input before.

Comment: "Use parameterized XPath queries (e.g. using XQuery). This will help ensure separation between data plane and control plane". does it says about the precompiled xpath expressions, even             
             XPathExpression filterCriteriaPathExpression = xpath.compile(filterCriteria);
                final boolean criteriaMatched = (boolean) filterCriteriaPathExpression.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.BOOLEAN);
                if (!criteriaMatched) {..
Sonar Still reports the issue even using the Xpath queries